# How can an NSCell detect the model key path it's bound to?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

Imagine the following:

- You have an NSTableView with multiple columns.
- Each NSTableColumn is bound to the same NSArrayController (we'll call it `myArrayController`).
- This array controller holds many instances of a model class.
- One column has an NSPopupButtonCell where `selectedObject` is bound to `myArrayController.arrangedObject.somePropertyOfTheModel`.
- The table gets properly populated.

**Q**: How can an NSCell detect the *model* key path it's bound to?  (`somePropertyOfTheModel` in this example)

I'm trying to make a cell reusable by not having it assume its represented value is always from `somePropertyOfTheModel` (could be from `somethingElse`).  Upon a given action, it needs to bind the `content` of a 2nd controller to `somePropertyOfTheModel` or `somethingElse`.

**[Edited] A bit more (maybe too much?) explanation:**
I'm creating a popup-button which displays a few preset values of a property, and a "Custom Value" item which triggers a PopOver window to allows configuration of the property.  I want to make it so that I can drop this cell into a table and having it manage the PopOver much like it already manages its own Menu.

**What I've tried:**

1. `[self representedObject]` returns the actual value. Setting it as `content` to the 2nd controller is all good and well... but whenever the model's property changes, the 2nd controller won't be notified since it's tied to the actual instance of the value... not a binding to the model property.
2. Querying the cell's binding gives me nothing:

   ```
   [[self infoForBinding:@"selectedObject"] objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey];   // nil returned
   [[self infoForBinding:@"selectedObject"] objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey];  // nil returned
   ```
3. Querying the cell's control's (the NSTableView) binding doesn't give me much:

   ```
   [(NSTableView*)[self controlView] infoForBinding:@"content"] objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey];   // returns myArrayController or a poxy to it.
   [(NSTableView*)[self controlView] infoForBinding:@"content"] objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey];  // returns @"arrangedObject"
   // running the same but for @"selectedObject" returns nothing but nils
   ```

I'd like to query the NSTableColumn itself -- that's where the bindings are defined in IB -- but cell's aren't aware of their existence (unless I've overlooked something obvious).  Even passing via NSTableView, no method returns an NSTableColumn for a given cell (and considering prototype cells, I doubt it would help).

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a co-mingling of view and controller layers, so, from a strict MVC design point of view, you may want to look for some other way to accomplish this. It's an interesting question, though!

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand what you're saying by co-mingling views and controllers. But wouldn't this be _somewhat_ similar to the existing relationship between the NSPopupButtonCell and its menu? If we think of menus as windows in that, they are unique "floating" entities which track mouse events, then wouldn't it be natural for the popup button to have a hidden menu controller (albeit hidden from developpers) much like how you'd have a controller for a window?  I must admit, I can't think of another way to split the view & controller and still make it as self-standing as NSPopupButtonCell.

Comment: The problem is that cells are not bound to anything, so you're looking in the wrong place.