# Getting keypath of NSArrayController key through selected cell of NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have NSTableView with connected NSArrayController. NSArrayController has some keys and they are represented with corresponding columns in NSTableView. I try to find the way to get the corresponding keypath of NSArrayController through selected column in NSTableView. How can I do this?

Comment: Get the keypath where?  In some NSTableViewDelegate method?

Comment: Directly or in some delegate method.

Comment: Would you consider your question a duplicate of this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895060/how-can-an-nscell-detect-the-model-key-path-its-bound-to

Comment: It, at least, has some snippets of using "infoForBinding" which you could use if you have a pointer to the NSTableColumn